# Что является грамматической основой предложения в данных предложениях?

Tags: синтаксис

Что является грамматической основой предложения в данных предложениях?

> - С каждым днём идти становилось всё труднее и труднее.
> - Один след показался мне каким-то странным.
> - Впереди были видны отпечатки тигровых лап.
> - Они будут вам очень рады.
> - Первый был брат Фёдор Фёдорович.

Answer (score 4):

*Идти* - подлежащее; *становилось всё труднее и труднее* - сказуемое.
Это двусоставное предложение с инфинитивом в роли подлежащего, потому что сказуемое возможно заменить конструкцией с формой творительного падежа:идти становилось делом всё более трудным. Следовательно, это прямая оценка действия

*След* - подлежащее; *показался странным* - сказуемое. *Один* - не числительное, а местоимение в значении "какой-то из ряда похожих", это определение.

*Отпечатки* - подлежащее; *были видны* - сказуемое.

*Они* - подлежащее; *будут рады* - сказуемое.

*Фёдор Фёдорович* - подлежащее; *был первый* - сказуемое. *Брат* - приложение, т. е. особый вид определения, указывающий на степень родства.

Comment: Согласна со всем, Людмила, кроме пятого предложения. Я сомневаюсь по поводу приложения. И ещё, там, где один след, нет контекста. Возможно, три других следа были обычными, а только один показался странным, тогда не факт, что один - это определение.

Answer (score 1):

Идти становилось всё труднее и труднее - сказуемое
Один след - подлежащее, показался странным - сказуемое
Отпечатки - подлежащее, были видны - сказуемое
Они - подлежащее, будут рады - сказуемое
Брат - подлежащее, был первый - сказуемое

Answer (score 0):

1) Становилось труднее (труднее что? идти)
2) След показался
3) Были видны отпечатки.
4) Они будут рады.
5) Брат Фёдор Фёдорович был первым.